# Constraining higher-kinded types for a Function1's argument and result type

Tags: scala, existential-type, higher-kinded-types

Given some higher-kinded types:

```
trait Impl [S]
trait Event[S, A]
trait Key  [A]
```

How can I rewrite the following definition:

```
def declare[A](fun: Impl[_] => Event[_, A]): Key[A] = ???
```

to constrain the `fun` argument to actually be `Impl[S] => Event[S, A]` *for some* `S`. For example, in the following case:

```
trait Impl[S] { def ev1: Event[S, Int]; def ev2: Event[T, Int] }
```

This would be a valid call:

```
declare(_.ev1)
```

but this not:

```
declare(_.ev2)  // this currently compiles
```

**EDIT**

Here comes a more complete example which shows exactly why I run into problems:

```
trait Sys  [S <: Sys[S]]
trait Event[S <: Sys[S], A, Repr]

trait Decl {
  type Impl[S <: Sys[S]]

  protected def declare[U](fun: Impl[_] => Event[_, U, Impl[_]]): Unit = ???
}
```

The following event declaring companion object fails to compile:

```
object Test extends Decl {
  type Impl[S <: Sys[S]] = Test[S]

  case class Renamed(name: String)

  declare[Renamed](_.renamed)
}

trait Test[S <: Sys[ S]] {
  def renamed: Event[S, Test.Renamed, Test[S]]
}
```

due to some problem of matching types:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Event[_$1,Test.Renamed,Test[_$1]] where type _$1
 required: Event[_, Test.Renamed, Test.Impl[_]]
Note: _$1 <: Any, but trait Event is invariant in type S.
You may wish to define S as +S instead. (SLS 4.5)
Note: Test[_$1] <: Test[_], but trait Event is invariant in type Repr.
You may wish to define Repr as +Repr instead. (SLS 4.5)
          declare[ Renamed ]( _.renamed )
                                ^
```

If I change the function type to `Impl[_] => Event[_, U, _]` it compiles, but I would really like to regain some type-safety.

Comment: Does it need to be existential? Can you not just add a type parameter to `declare`?

Comment: I mean if I'm interpreting what you mean by "for some" correctly you could write `(Impl[s] => Event[s,A]) forSome {type s}` but I'm not sure what the advantage is over making `S` a type parameter of `declare`.

Comment: @Owen Yes, it needs to be this way. The `declare` is performed from a companion object and declares the events of the implementing class, irrespective of the system which is used to instantiate that class. I am just realising that my problem is the syntax for `Function1` -- so I added an answer showing the right syntax.

Comment: Is there any chance what your are actually looking for is `Impl[s] => Event[s,A] forAll {type s}` (not actually valid scala)?

Comment: @Owen -- yeah, I exactly realised this a minute ago. A pity that is not a valid statement... (I would call it `forAny` :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the existential type cannot be given with the 'nice' `Function1` syntax:

```
// error: not found: type S
def declare[A](fun: Impl[S] => Event[S, A] forSome { type S }): Key[A] = ???
```

...but it works when using the normal syntax:

```
// yes!
def declare[A](fun: Function1[Impl[S], Event[S, A]] forSome { type S }): Key[A] = ???
```

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, now my nice use site is screwed

```
missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.renamed)
[error]    declare[ Renamed ]( _.renamed )
```

So I have to stick with the type-unsafe version :-(

I guess I would need a new feature like `(Impl[S] => Event[S, A]) forAny { type S }`...

Comment: Adding parentheses also makes it work. Might be a precedence issue.

Comment: you could have a look at http://existentialtype.net/2008/03/09/higher-rank-impredicative-polymorphism-in-scala/ . It is over my head, though.